# jQuery's getScript function can't find my .js.erb templates in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
$(function() {
  $("#ll_search").submit(function() {
    $.getScript(document.location.pathname + '/index.js.erb');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Line 3 in the snippet results in the following error:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/labs/index.js.erb").`

I'm running Rails 3.1, which means jQuery is default. I triple-checked that a file "index.js.erb" actually exists. jQuery can't seem to see it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `document.location.pathname` will give you a root level path, which will (by default) in Rails take you to the public directory (unless a corresponding route exists). If you need to render this js file at request time (not recommended as far as performance) create an endpoint that renders the js and returns it appropriately with the right MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the raw ERB version (nothing on the client side would know what to do with it) and the script is probably in `/assets` in Rails 3.1 so try one of these:

```
$.getScript('/labs/index.js');
$.getScript('/assets/labs/index.js');
$.getScript('/assets/index.js');
```

I'm guessing a bit about where things are though.